# Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

If I use  the following commands:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point()
```

all works fine.

If I run the following commands:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point()
```

I receive this error message:

> Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Answer (score 0):

ggtern has a `ggplot()` function as well, so the duplicate name is messing it up. Best option is to load the packages in the opposite order (the last package loaded always wins when there are duplicate names), or try the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)
p <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + ggplot2::geom_point()
```

Comment: Sorry  also with your suggestion nothing is changed, the error persist.

Comment: It works fine on my computer. Have you tried restarting R and reloading the packages from scratch?

Comment: I have restarted R and reloaded the packages many time, but the error remain. I work with a MacOS Big Sur 10.16, with R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31), ggtern_3.3.0 and  ggplot2_3.3.5.9000